# Can you get docx xml off the Clipboard in C# (.NET 4.0)

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, clipboard, docx

It's easy to get things like Html, rtf, UnicodeText, and images off of the clipboard using this:

Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html); or Clipboard.GetImage(); or what have you.

Is there a way to get docx xml off of the clipboard (the kind that you get if you look at a saved docx file)? Does a copy/cut in a word document even put docx xml on the clipboard?

Comment: nope - you have to send it to the clipboard before you can get it. the object model in Word 2007/2010 allows you to get the Open XML (and then you can do anything you like with it).

Comment: Hey, do you still remember if you found a solution for this ?

Comment: Never found a solution. Had to nix the feature. Left in drag drop of docx files though because that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a workaround by grabbing the file name of the Word docx file and then reading it to get the XML behind it, then pasting it to clipboard.

While your there you can

1. manipulate docx using http://docx.codeplex.com/
2. put HTML on clipboard       http://cathalscorner.blogspot.ca/2009/10/converting-docx-into-doc-pdf-html.html
3. Get doc XML part - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa982683(v=office.12).aspx
4. How to get Plain Text of a Word Document using Open XML (CSOpenXmlGetPlainText) -                   https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSOpenXmlGetPlainText-554918c3

.

```
    public static string ToStringWithDeclaration(this XDocument doc)
    {
        if (doc == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("doc");
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(builder))
        {
            doc.Save(writer);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public static void SetFileDropList(StringCollection filePaths) {

        IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (!data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        return;

        string[] filePaths = (string[])data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        foreach (string fileLoc in filePaths) {

            if (Path.GetExtension(fileLoc)==".docx"){

                  if (File.Exists(c)) {

                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
                        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileLoc);

                       Clipboard.SetText(xDoc.ToStringWithDeclaration(), TextDataFormat.Html);

                 }
            }
        }
```